# git-p4 sync on different branch and repo

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4, git-fast-import

I'm trying to mirror a perforce repository, and git-p4 performs well enough on the main branch. I simply have to call `git-p4 rebase`. I'm also trying to mirror a different branch, but that's not working out so easily. I thought I could just do a `git-p4 rebase --branch=p4/whatever //open/branches/whatever` but `rebase` appears to ignore those tags, and if I do a `sync` instead I get the error message: `fast-import failed: warning: Not updating refs/heads/p4/whatever (new tip 14f7e14e5079bb730363440901adee102e5f04c9 does not contain 0ca89b0333f408367e3676720b109a08cc40b3ae)`

My initial import was a sync with @all, why wouldn't it be able to update, or is there a different/better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

git-p4 doesn't work well when you try to have more than one p4 head in git.  Sad I know.  What I ended up doing was having each main/branch in separate git repos.  It doesn't allow for branch management I know.

Also @all does not work for me either because it tries to figure out the branches and then fails.  I only use git-p4 to get the latest and use the history from there onwards.